# Скопировать текст в буфер обмена javafx

Tags: javafx

При нажатии на кнопку надо скопировать текст из TextField в буфер обмена. Есть вариант на Swing, который подходит идеально, но надо на JavaFX.

```
public static void setClipboard(String str) {
    StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(str);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JavaFX тоже есть класс для работы с буфером обмена

```
public static void setClipboard(String str) {
    Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.putString(str);
    clipboard.setContent(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код для контроллера. Метод необходимо задать, как обработчик для конкретной кнопки.

```
@FXML
private void handleBtnCopy(){
    // create clipboard content
    final ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
    clipboardContent.putString(this.textField.getText());

    // set clipboard content
    Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(clipboardContent);
}
```